# How to convert a tuple to a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuple(each tuple is of 3 elements) and I want to convert it into dictionary, how to do it in most efficient way? Here is the example:

```
[(980898, 9977, 1),
 (899979879, 23, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (980898, 98789797, 1),
 (98789797, 980898, 1),
 (1, 756735, 1),
 (1, 3344, 1),
 (23, 4, 1),
 (534, 23, 1),
 (756735, 1, 1),
 (9977, 980898, 1),
 (23, 899979879, 1),
 (4, 23, 1),
 (756735, 980898, 1),
 (3344, 1, 1),
 (980898, 756735, 1),
 (23, 534, 1)]
```

I want the following dict:

```
{1: {1: 2, 3344: 1, 756735: 1},
 4: {23: 1},
 23: {4: 1, 534: 1, 899979879: 1},
 534: {23: 1},
 3344: {1: 1},
 9977: {980898: 1},
 756735: {1: 1, 980898: 1},
 980898: {9977: 1, 756735: 1, 98789797: 1},
 98789797: {980898: 1},
 899979879: {23: 1}}
```

Here first element of the tuple is the key and next element becomes the key in the dict of first element and final element becomes the value for the second key.

I have tried the following but it gives incomplete dictionary :

```
finalDict = {a:{b:c} for a,b,c in e}
print finalDict

{1: {3344: 1}, 980898: {756735: 1}, 4: {23: 1}, 98789797: {980898: 1}, 899979879: {23: 1}, 3344: {1: 1}, 534: {23: 1}, 23: {534: 1}, 9977: {980898: 1}, 756735: {980898: 1}}
```

Comment: How would the transformation from your tuple to the dict happen, by what rules? Also, what have you tried yet, where have you failed and what errors do you get?

Comment: I have edited and added what I tried, it constructs the dictionary but only puts one value corresponding to a key.

Comment: So, you want to make first element of the tuple to be a key, a nd the rest of the tuple to be a value of key in dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
{a:{b:c} for a,b,c in e}
```

overwrites the values of the main dictionary. You can use `setdefault` to access the value of the main dictionary if it already exists:

```
d = {}
for a, b, c in e:
    d.setdefault(a, {})[b] = c
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d = [(980898, 9977, 1),
 (899979879, 23, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (980898, 98789797, 1),
 (98789797, 980898, 1),
 (1, 756735, 1),
 (1, 3344, 1),
 (23, 4, 1),
 (534, 23, 1),
 (756735, 1, 1),
 (9977, 980898, 1),
 (23, 899979879, 1),
 (4, 23, 1),
 (756735, 980898, 1),
 (3344, 1, 1),
 (980898, 756735, 1),
 (23, 534, 1)]

from collections import defaultdict

D = defaultdict(dict)

for a, b, c in d:
    D[a][b] = c

for k in sorted(D):
    print k, D[k]
```

---

```
1 {3344: 1, 1: 2, 756735: 1}
4 {23: 1}
23 {4: 1, 534: 1, 899979879: 1}
534 {23: 1}
3344 {1: 1}
9977 {980898: 1}
756735 {1: 1, 980898: 1}
980898 {9977: 1, 98789797: 1, 756735: 1}
98789797 {980898: 1}
899979879 {23: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code only keeps the first encountered value for a given key. You can use `defaultdict` from the `collections` module to initialize `result` with a fresh `dict` and then set the key to the value as encountered in your list of tuples.

```
#all_tuples = [(...), (...), ...]
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(dict)
for uid, k, v in all_tuples :
    result[uid][k] = v

dict(result)
```

Output:

```
{1: {1: 2, 3344: 1, 756735: 1},
 4: {23: 1},
 23: {4: 1, 534: 1, 899979879: 1},
 534: {23: 1},
 3344: {1: 1},
 9977: {980898: 1},
 756735: {1: 1, 980898: 1},
 980898: {9977: 1, 756735: 1, 98789797: 1},
 98789797: {980898: 1},
 899979879: {23: 1}}
```